# Recommend a Programmer's Dictionary for MS Word

Tags: ms-word, spell-checking

MS Word is nothing short of irritating to use for any sort of software development work (notes, documentation, etc.), which is likely why many people use other tools (notepad++, etc.)

Asides from turning off spell-check & grammar check functionality for a word document, our only other option is to create a new style for the document, and disable proofing for that style, as documented here: [Systems documentation and MS Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306108/systems-documentation-and-ms-word)

---

**Has anyone out there come accross any particularily good custom dictionaries which covers words common to engineering, software development, etc.?**

---

This would certainly be helpful in aleviating the frustration level a bit. The dictionary could always be imported into other word processing tools as well.

Cheers and TIA - Ray

Comment: I think the question is, **if you know there are alternatives and can name at least one, why are you still using Word?**

Comment: +1 for this. I asked myself this originally as well, but the truth is, .docx files get passed around fairly frequently at most offices and there always seem to be little "gotchas" with compatibility when using other tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the language to something obscure like Farci or Klingon.